AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute '__version__' but when just trying to use ResNet50 (TensorFlow 2.16.1)
A simple code using Jupyter Notebook:
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights="imagenet")

Is giving an odd error related to keras version:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights="imagenet")

File ~\anaconda3\envs\rnap\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py:181, in KerasLazyLoader.__getattr__(self, item)
    179   return super(types.ModuleType, self).__getattribute__(item)
    180 if not self._tfll_initialized:
--> 181   self._initialize()
    182 if self._tfll_keras_version == "keras_3":
    183   if (
    184       self._tfll_mode == "v1"
    185       and not self._tfll_submodule
    186       and item.startswith("compat.v1.")
    187   ):

File ~\anaconda3\envs\rnap\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py:149, in KerasLazyLoader._initialize(self)
    146 try:
    147   import keras  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
--> 149   if keras.__version__.startswith("3."):
    150     # This is the Keras 3.x case.
    151     keras_version = "keras_3"
    152     package_name = "keras._tf_keras.keras"

AttributeError: module 'keras' has no attribute '__version__'

Is it a bug from TensorFlow 2.16.1 or I am doing something very wrong? If it isn't my fault, how can I perform any sort of workaround? Thanks in advance.
Basically I am just tried to look in other Stack Overflow posts and I've used Copilot, but with no success.

This typically happens when there's a conflict or confusion between different versions of TensorFlow and its dependencies, particularly with Keras.TensorFlow 2.x has integrated Keras as its official high-level API, so tf.keras is the recommended way to use Keras within TensorFlow. The error message suggests TensorFlow might be looking for a separate installation of Keras (keras), which might not exist or might be conflicting with tf.keras.

Make sure you have TensorFlow installed correctly, and it should come with tf.keras included. If you installed an additional separate keras library, it might lead to conflicts.Check the versions of TensorFlow and Keras by running:**import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.version)
print(tf.keras.version)**Make sure you're using the TensorFlow environment where you installed tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu if using GPU acceleration.

I have tried several times in different conda environments, and I have never, ever installed a separated keras (I am aware of the possible conflicts)
